# Many to Many Question/Problem!

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How does rails handle many to many relationships?

I am trying to create a user which can get assigned a pre defined group from the groups table.

Which is what the user_group table is for.. how is this done?

Picture of ERD below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFzyP.png

Comment: Why the non-standard table names? Can you stick with Rails conventions? The conventions are plural table names (`groups`, `users`) and a join table arranged alphabetically (`groups_users`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) on many to many and another [one](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes) that should work with your DB

Answer (score 1):

Quick primer on Rails relationships -

```
1:n - Has Many
n:1 - Belongs To
n:n - Has And Belongs To Many (HASBTM)
```

For your specific situation, simply call `has_and_blongs_to_many` from both your User and Group classes -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Comment: Ive got that but when i do this inside my edit i get


`<% for group in @groups %>
   <%= check_box_tag "user[group_ids][]", group.id, @user.groups.include?(group) %>
   <%= group.description %>
   <% end %>`



Could not find table 'groups_users'

Comment: @Ahmet, you have to create the groups_users table.

Comment: @Anupam, for completeness, you should also mention the join model option: `has_many :through`.